# How can I remove the faucet cover I dropped down the drain?

Tags: drain, bathtub

I dropped the plastic (H) round faucet cover of my bathtub faucet down my tub drain, and now the water will barely drain out. What do I do.

Comment: Is this a basement tub? Do you have access to the drain assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Fish it out. A piece of gum (or tape) on the end of a stick might work, as might a clipped coat hanger with a 90° hook at one end.

Comment: Or, if you're exceptionally lucky, the trap might be accessible (eg, from the basement if this is a ground-floor tub) and might have a clean-out plug or be reasonably easy to dismount/remount. Lesson: Always cover drains before starting disassembly -- if nothing else, stuff a rag in the drain -- to catch lost parts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vacuum that has a wand or a shopvac.

Comment: Make sure the vacuum is designed to take in water if you try this, since there will be water in the trap.